# library for sharding mysql in Java

Tags: mysql, hibernate, sharding

Sooner, we are going to shard our mysql database to achieve horizontal scaling. Our technology stack is based on spring, hibernate.

However, I haven't been able to find any alternate to hibernate which would support sharding at the application level.

I read about hibernate shards but it is no longer maintained, so I would not be suitable to use it in production.

Moreover, with companies like facebook, twitter, digg using mysql sharding, I am surprised that there is not GA hibernate alternative to sharding.

I would appreciate if someone could suggest some persistence framework in java which supports sharding out of the box.

Thanks in advance!!!!

Answer (score -1):

Disclaimer: I work for [ScaleBase](http://www.scalebase.com), a provider of a complete MySQL scale-out solution an "automatic sharding machine" if you like.

I'm a believer of a solution that is outside the code. This way the entire eco-system including ad-hoc and administration queries from MySQL command line and utilities like MySQLDump are also "aware" of the sharding.

This was the main disadvantage of Hib Shards, or any sharding framework that would be limited to the persistence layer, inside the application code.

We have some good resources about key-based sharding (hash, range, list) and data distribution on our site: http://www.scalebase.com/products/database-sharding/ http://www.scalebase.com/resources/webinars/ - (search for "WEBINAR – 10.23.12: Benefits of Automatic Data Distribution")

I also invite you to look at my blog: http://database-scalability.blogspot.com

Hope I helped.